# Keycloak 15.0.1 failed to start because of missing library

Tags: keycloak, wildfly

I try to install a Keycloak 15.0.1 server on Debian 12. I have some issues when I start my server because of missing library. I fix the first one regarding the postgresql driver by adding new jboss module using the jboss-cli.sh add susbsystem.
But a lot of librairy still missing and it could be difficult to solve them one by one.
Does it have a global solution to fix those lib ?

```
{
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.offlineClientSessions",
        "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.authenticationSessions",
        "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.clientSessions",
        "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.actionTokens"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.naming.context.java.app.auth.AppName is missing [org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.actionTokens, org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.clientSessions, org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.offlineClientSessions, org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.authenticationSessions]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.app.auth is missing [org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.actionTokens, org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.clientSessions, org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.offlineClientSessions, org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.authenticationSessions]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.module.auth.auth.ValidatorFactory is missing [org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.actionTokens, org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.clientSessions, org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.offlineClientSessions, org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.authenticationSessions]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.module.auth.auth.ModuleName is missing [org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.actionTokens, org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.clientSessions, org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.offlineClientSessions, org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.authenticationSessions]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.module.auth.auth is missing [org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.actionTokens, org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.clientSessions, org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.offlineClientSessions, org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.authenticationSessions]",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"keycloak-server.war\".jca.cachedConnectionManagerSetupProcessor is missing [org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.actionTokens, org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.clientSessions, org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.offlineClientSessions, org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.authenticationSessions]",
        "jboss.deployment.discovery.\"keycloak-server.war\" is missing [org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.actionTokens, org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.clientSessions, org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.offlineClientSessions, org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.authenticationSessions]",
        "jboss.concurrent.ee.context.config.auth.auth is missing [org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.actionTokens, org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.clientSessions, org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.offlineClientSessions, org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.authenticationSessions]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.module.auth.auth.InAppClientContainer is missing [org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.actionTokens, org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.clientSessions, org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.offlineClientSessions, org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.authenticationSessions]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.module.auth.auth.InstanceName is missing [org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.actionTokens, org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.clientSessions, org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.offlineClientSessions, org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.authenticationSessions]",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"keycloak-server.war\".INSTALL is missing [org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.actionTokens, org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.clientSessions, org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.offlineClientSessions, org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.authenticationSessions]",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"keycloak-server.war\".ejb3.client-context.registration-service is missing [org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.actionTokens, org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.clientSessions, org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.offlineClientSessions, org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.authenticationSessions]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.module.auth.auth.Validator is missing [org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.actionTokens, org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.clientSessions, org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.offlineClientSessions, org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.authenticationSessions]"
    ]
}
```